# Facebook Credits/Payment API in C# or VB .net?

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

I can't seem to find any code examples anywhere online that even hint at any way to use the Facebook API or Facebook SDK with C#.net (or even VB.net) to use the Facebook Credits features.

Does anyone know of any .Net examples that could help show how to use the Facebook Credits features?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the calls required to use the credits API are actually just graph calls which will work fine with the C# SDK. The other stuff like the the callbacks you are going to have to do own your own.

Answer (score 1):

Well i think the [Documentation by Facebook](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/creditsapi/) is Sufficient enough.
I have not used Facebook C# SDK but For use in .Net you can simply use [HttpRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.aspx)/[HttpResponse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.aspx) classes to do Send/Recive data.

For parsing JSON you can use [JSON.Net](http://json.net) or use [JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx) Class.
Here is an [Example](http://shekhar-pro.blogspot.com/2011/01/serializing-and-deserializing-data-from.html) with JavaScriptSerializer. Its for Facebook Feeds but you can use somthing similar for Credits too.

Answer (score 1):

I see this is an old one, i'd like to contribute, having just fought this fight, and resorted to using network monitor to capture the raw tcp traffic to figure out what was going on.

1. Facebook is NOT sending a content-type of json, its 
   "ContentType:  application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
2. They aren't sending JSON!! they are sending a form post

This caused no end of grief for me. I'm including an actual network snag of their data. I have no idea what they are doing , and its directly against their documentation. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/credits/callback/

"signed_request=[The signed request]&buyer=[my id]&receiver=[my id]&order_id=247146405372045&order_info=%22100credits%22&test_mode=1&method=payments_get_items"

TO tie it more directly to the question, if you're using asp.net, you can just accept a form post. If you using WCF, its a hassle

1. Accept Stream as the input to your WCF method
2. parse it out,

   ```
   //Get the Stream
   var postStream = new StreamReader(input).ReadToEnd();


   //parse the string
   var vals = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(postStream);
   ```